# Pandas. Столбцы в сводной таблице

Tags: python, pandas

Вопрос по сводной таблице. У меня есть датафрейм:
[image: Исходный датафрейм]

При создании сводной таблицы `df.pivot_table(['Не пройдено', 'Процент прохождения'], index=['Класс'], columns='Предмет', fill_value=0)` у меня получается такая таблица:

[image: Сводная]

Не могу понять как мне сделать сводную, чтобы получилось так:
[image: Желаемая сводная]

Проще говоря мне нужно строки с названием предмета("Предмет") поставить на уровень выше, чем строки со статусом предмета("Не пройдено" и "Процент прохождения")

[image: Код]
Исходные данные

```
   Класс    Не пройдено Процент прохождения Предмет
0   9А             1         75.0           Русский язык
1   9Б             20        75.3           Русский язык
2   9А             31        90.5           Литература
3   9Б             142       94.8           Литература
4   9А             17        94.1           История
5   9Б             117       95.1           История
```

Comment: Пример исходных данных в воспроизводимом виде приведите.

Comment: Добавил исходные данные, прошу простить меня если не правильно их добавил, так как впервые пользуюсь сайтом.

Answer (score 1):

При ваших исходных данных попробуйте так:

```
res = df.pivot_table(index="Класс", columns=["Предмет"]).swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

res получится:

```
Предмет     История                      Литература                     Русский язык                    
        Не пройдено Процент прохождения Не пройдено Процент прохождения  Не пройдено Процент прохождения
Класс                                                                                                   
9А               17                94.1          31                90.5            1                75.0
9Б              117                95.1         142                94.8           20                75.3
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало!